# Getting wrong output results in executing bash script

Tags: bash

Getting wrong output results in executing the below bash script. The $SPLUNK_DB is missing from the output.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat index_name`
do
echo "
[$i]
coldPath = $SPLUNK_DB/$i/colddb
homePath = $SPLUNK_DB/$i/db
thawedPath = $SPLUNK_DB/$i/thaweddb " >> idx_list
echo " "
done

Wrong output results:
[web]
coldPath = /web/colddb
homePath = /web/db
thawedPath = /web/thaweddb


Expecting this output result.
[web]
coldPath = $SPLUNK_DB/web/colddb
homePath = $SPLUNK_DB/web/db
thawedPath = $SPLUNK_DB/web/thaweddb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the `$`. Because you are using double quotes, the $ is being interpreted.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat index_name`
do
echo "
[$i]
coldPath = \$SPLUNK_DB/$i/colddb
homePath = \$SPLUNK_DB/$i/db
thawedPath = \$SPLUNK_DB/$i/thaweddb " >> idx_list
echo " "
done
```